# No Audio on Raspbain

Tags: audio

my raspberry pi 400 has no sound , it does not work at all .
I have tried many operating systems like ubuntu , manjaro but still not work .
i have searched online may be i fine a solution but no success .
I am using sound through HDMI . Sorry man i am a new user here so that i can not post a perfect posts .
I will be greatful if someone can help !
Here is my config.txt file :

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
framebuffer_width=1280
framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Run in 64-bit mode
arm_64bit=1

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
```

Comment: We need more details... What audio connection / setup? Which OS exactly? Have you tried PiOS? Have you made any changes in config.txt or raspi-config? etc, etc.

Comment: thank you for your reply ,

Comment: i am using PiOS 64 bit , i did some changes in the file /boot/config.txt , i uncommented the line : hdmi_drive = 2 still no audio. remarkable is that i have another sd card with kali linux distro and the audio works

Comment: Pls add any additional info to your query; not as a comment

Comment: You haven't told us how you're trying to get sound out of your system...

Comment: Sorry , i did not understand your question(how i am trying to get sound out of my system) can you please make your question clear ?

Comment: Do you use sound through HDMI or a different system? Can you also post your config.txt to your query And as requested before pls add additional info to your query; don't put it in comments